# relatime not working as documented

Tags: ssd, fstab

I have installed SSD (Transcend 128 370S) on Ubuntu - 15.10 having Kernel - 4.2.0-16. After installation I'm trying SSD optimization as given [in link](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization). I have added relatime to fstab on / but I can still see modified and access time getting update and this is not working per documentation. Please help me explaining or is this a bug ?
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPLTo.png)

Comment: Please elaborate more on `can still see modified and access time getting update `

Comment: Added sample screenshot, Accessed Time shows as latest even though it's not modified recently (exclude tmp folder from this context)

Answer (score 1):

First please check whether or not atime has actually been used as mount option.
In a terminal type:

```
mount
```

This should show you all mounts, including all mount options, such as relatime
This could look something like this:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

So the mount options in this example root dir were 'rw' and 'relatime'

If this does not show relatime for your root dir then relatime was not used.
Check that relatime is set in your fstab

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

Did you reboot after you changed the setting.
If not, please reboot now.
If that does not help please try

```
sudo mount -o remount,relatime /
```

This should manually set relatime.
Check again with:

```
mount
```

If this helped, then probably your rootdir used the fstab from initrd to mount your rootdir, in stead of the fstab in your normal filesystem.
Look on the internet or askubuntu to find out how to change fstab in initrd. (Warning, making mistakes in initrd can make your computer not boot)

Please also make sure you understand relatime.
The first time a file or directory is read after it has been written to, the time accessed time (atime) will be updated.
Only the second and later times it is read (after a write), the atime is not updated anymore.
So the way to test is:

```
Create a file or directory.
Read the file or directory once.
Look at the directory contents
atime should be upodated now
Wait some time
Read the file or directoy again.
Look at the directory contents again.
atime should not be updated now.
```

Comment: I did changed in fstab but I noticed that relatime is coming from initrd seems default config. Example helped in understanding relatime config. I went through blog post and understood well (accessed time update only when changed in last modified, it also updated if access time is day old, and on restart as I tried couple of time). 
tmp, etc, run, sys, dev, proc, var seems to be volatile. adding another question on this note.

Comment: @AslamSayyed run, sys, dev & proc are mount points of virtual file systems. They are never written to a physical disk.